# Javascript: attaching OOP methods to events and the 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, event-handling, this

I am new to OOP Javascript and am having trouble with the `this` keyword and events.

What I'm trying to achieve is: I have multiple DOM objects and want to not only bind a common event to them, but keep some data about the aforementioned objects in a global container (to increase runtime performance).

So what I do is basically this:

```
function ClassThatDoesSomething() {
    /* keeps node ids for processing in this.init */
    this.nodes = new Array();

    /* keeps processed node data for fast access */
    this.nodeData = new Array();

    this.sthAddNodes = function(/* ids */) {
        /* appends node ids to local variable (this.nodeData) */
    }

    function init() {
        /* gathers data from all nodes that were 
           added before and stores it in this.nodeData */

        /* here, unsurprisingly, 'this' references the window element*/

        addEvent(window,'scroll',this.scroll);
    }

    function scroll() {
        /* do stuff when user scrolls the page */

        /* 'this' references the window element here too */
    }
    addEvent(window,'load',this.init);
}
```

Later, in the document body, I could just add this:

```
var Ctds = new ClassThatDoesSomething();
```

And further on, add DOM elements by:

```
Ctds.addNodes(ids);
```

No further implementation code would be required.

***QUESTION:*** How to access the *JS class instance* in the `init` and `scroll` methods and **not** the *window element*.

It doesn't have to be through the `this` keyword, I know, but still I didn't come up with anything.

P.S.

- `addEvent` is an extremely basic function to attach events, it's just IE/Fx friendly and does nothing else.
- The code I'm writing is already functional, but in procedural form, I just wanted to OOP'd it.
- As a minor sub-question, I got the impression somehow, that getter/setter methods are discouraged in javascript, is it okay if I use them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing I notice is that neither `init` nor `scroll` is a method on the instance.

So you only need to add `init` and not `this.init` to the load event:

```
addEvent(window,'load',init); // No "this." needed
```

And similarly:

```
addEvent(window,'scroll',scroll);
```

If you do decide to move them to the class (eg `this.scroll` and `this.init` etc), you can save a reference to `this` and refer to it in an anonymous function passed to `addEvent`:

```
var self = this;

this.init = function() {
    addEvent(window, 'scroll', function() {
        self.scroll()
    })
};

this.scroll = function() { /* ... */ };

addEvent(window,'load',function() {
    self.init()
});
```

This is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures).

Comment: Wow, so many answers, I'm overwhelmed, thanks all. So anyway, how exactly would a method be defined? (dumb question, sorry)

Comment: @Raveren: well that is a big question. This code sample is an example of what crockford calls "privileged" member declaration. See http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html  That's actually an advanced approach to OOP in JavaScript. If you want to start with the basic of defining classes in JavaScript, start here: http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.foo = "bar";
    var me = this;
    function myClosure() {
        doSomethingWith(me.foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not determined until execution of the function. When attaching an event listener, you are passing a **function**, which does not carry scope with it. Therefore, on the specified event, the function is running in the scope of `window`, meaning that `this` will be equal to `window`. To force execution in a particular scope, you can use tricks like creating a new variable to equal `this`, such as:

```
var that = this;
...
addEvent(window,'scroll', function() {
    that.scroll()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to the Function prototype that allows you to bind any function to any object:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(object) {
   var __method = this;
   return function() {
      return __method.apply(object, arguments);
   };
};
```

Declare your event handlers in the instance (keeps things tidy):

```
function ClassThatDoesSomething() {

  this.events = {
    init: ClassThatDoesSomething.init.bind(this),
    scroll: ClassThatDoesSomething.scroll.bind(this),
    etc: ClassThatDoesSomething.etc.bind(this)
  };
  ...
}
```

Now whenever you reference your events, they'll be automatically bound to the class instance.  e.g.:

```
function init() {
  addEvent(window,'scroll',ClassThatDoesSomething.events.scroll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures for that:

```
function ClassThatDoesSomething() {
    var self=this;
    // ...

    function init() {
        addEvent(window,'scroll',self.scroll);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work because I just copied 'function init()' and don't make it 'this.init = function()'. And why do you think it is not a closure?

Comment: Also it is important how is this class used. The proper code is 'var myClassInstance = new ClassThatDoesSomething(); myClassInstance.init();'

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var ClassThatDoesSomething = function() {
    /* keeps node ids for processing in this.init */
    this.nodes = new Array();

    /* keeps processed node data for fast access */
    this.nodeData = new Array();
}

ClassThatDoesSomething.prototype.sthAddNodes = function(/* ids */) {
        /* appends node ids to local variable (this.nodeData) */
    }
}

ClassThatDoesSomething.prototype.init = function() {
        /* gathers data from all nodes that were 
           added before and stores it in this.nodeData */

        /* here, unsurprisingly, 'this' references the window element*/

        addEvent(window,'scroll',this.scroll);
    }
}
ClassThatDoesSomething.prototype.scroll = function() {
        /* do stuff when user scrolls the page */

        /* 'this' references the window element here too */
    }
    addEvent(window,'load',this.init);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This trick should work:

```
function ClassThatDoesSomething() {
...
    this.This = this;
...
}
```

Then inside those problematic methods you can use `'This'`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `this.This = this`. I can't even wrap my head around this.