# Calling a prototype function - not working

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I have the following code which control the position of an image gallery (which can be seen at steven.tlvweb.com). The scroll wheel currently controls the gallery position but the keydown events don't, and I would like them to. The alerts in the code below (keyLeft and keyRight) are seen but **this.parent.scroll** is not being called at all.

The argument sc just needs to be a positive or negative integer - that is what event.wheelDelta is after all so I am left wondering, what is the correct way to call this prototype function please?

```
/* //////////// ==== ImageFlow Constructor ==== //////////// */


function ImageFlow(oCont, xmlfile, horizon, size, zoom, border, start, interval) {
    this.oc = document.getElementById(oCont); 
this.scrollbar  = getElementsByClass(this.oc,   'div', 'scrollbar');
this.text       = getElementsByClass(this.oc,   'div', 'text');
this.bar        = getElementsByClass(this.oc,   'img', 'bar');
this.arL        = getElementsByClass(this.oc,   'img', 'arrow-left');
this.arR        = getElementsByClass(this.oc,   'img', 'arrow-right');
    this.bar.parent = this.oc.parent = this; 
    this.arL.parent = this.arR.parent = this;

    /* === handle mouse scroll wheel === */
    this.oc.onmousewheel = function () {
        this.parent.scroll(event.wheelDelta);
        return false;
    }

    var pleasework = this;

/* ==== add keydown events ==== */
    window.document.onkeydown=function(){  
        pleasework.keypress(event.keyCode);
        return false;
    }

}
/* //////////// ==== ImageFlow prototype ==== //////////// */
ImageFlow.prototype = {

scroll: function (sc) {
        if (sc < 0) {
            if (this.view < this.NF - 1) this.calc(1);
        } else {
            if (this.view > 0) this.calc(-1);
        }
    },


keypress : function (kp) {

    switch (kp) {
        case 39:
            //right Key
            if (this.view < this.NF - 1) this.calc(1);
            break;
        case 37:
            //left Key
            if (this.view > 0) this.calc(-1);
            break;
    }

    },

}
```

Thanks in advance
Steven (a novice Java programmer)

Comment: I am guessing you want to do `ImageFlow.prototype.scroll = function(sc) {`. Right now you're overwriting the prototype of the ImageFlow object, not adding a function to it.

Comment: Where are you getting `parent` from?

Comment: What are those `oc` and `parent` properties?

Comment: duplicate of [Javascript: attaching OOP methods to events and the 'this' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578034/javascript-attaching-oop-methods-to-events-and-the-this-keyword) and many others

Comment: @Bergi and mVChr - have added the declarations now in the above code.

Comment: Please add them in the right place and in the right order.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know I'm not doing it right Frank - I have tried using the code you suggest but have no idea where to put it at all!!! Please can you advise me. The mousewheel proves that the scrollwheel works - but I just can't call it after the keyDown event. I know I am asking for a lot but please please help me.

Comment: @StevenWinston can you create a short self-contained example that shows your problem? A site like jsFiddle may help you setting that up and then you can share the link here. Once both you and us are looking at the same thing, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @Bergi - order changed and in correct place - sorry!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - sorry Frank I don't know how to do this - I did not write the original code and am a novice. I just don't know why when I say `this.parent.scroll(120);` nothing is happening - I'll be honest I have no idea what all this THIS and PARENT stuff is about at the moment - and I try reading about it but I need to start at something more fundemental - I just need the line of code that will call scroll from within `window.document.onkeydown = function ()`

Comment: In that case I can only suggest that you follow a simpler tutorial on JavaScript first. Creating custom objects and adding methods to a prototype are not terribly complex, but Stack Overflow is a Q&A site - not a JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have programmed C before but this is just much different. I know it is not a tutorial but I just need one line don't I??? It's just one line of code that is wrong isn't it - I really need to complete this tonight and am struggling to read all the javascript tutorials (the language is bamboozling)

Comment: @StevenWinston: Read the [introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Did you notice I posted a link to the solution above? And forget about that `parent` property.

Comment: @Bergi - I'm afraid all that is far too complicated for me to understand, too much new jargon that I can't absorb. Is a solution even achievable or am I wasting my time and everyone elses. I have tried changing the code many times - how can I post again to show you?

Comment: it's something to do with the fact that the function is window.document.onkeydown and the this the code refers to is not correct. I guess I need to know what this I need to refer to.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to show your current code. Yes, the `this` in the event handler refers to the DOM element. You will need to create a variable (outside the handler) that holds the right reference, and use that - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578034/javascript-attaching-oop-methods-to-events-and-the-this-keyword). That variable is named `self`, `me` and `that` in the various answers.

Comment: @Bergi - OMG I got it working doing what you said in that last statement. Full working code above now! Thanks so much to you and Frank!!!!! If you ever come to Tel Aviv I owe you a few beers!!!!! Seriously!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use that `parent` property on the DOM elements. Instead, just create a closure over a local variable. So, replace

```
this.bar.parent = this.oc.parent = this; 
this.arL.parent = this.arR.parent = this;

/* === handle mouse scroll wheel === */
this.oc.onmousewheel = function () {
    this.parent.scroll(event.wheelDelta);
    return false;
}

/* ==== add keydown events ==== */
window.document.onkeydown=function(){  
    this.parent.keypress(event.keyCode);
    return false;
}
```

with

```
var parent = this;
this.oc.onmousewheel = function(e) {
    parent.scroll(e.wheelDelta);
    e.preventDefault();
};
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) { // notice this overwrites previous listeners
    parent.keypress(e.keyCode);
};
```